# How to make datepicker in MVVM treeview WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datepicker, treeview

I have a pretty complex question:
At my work, we use WPF with MVVM standards. 
On one of our UserControls, there is a treeview that loads all the tables from the database. For each table, the name is loaded in the list by the treeview. When you click on the table name, you can add data to that table from the screen.
Basically, it loads the column names from the table on the side, and lets you enter data and save. The records are then saved and added as children to the table. From here, selecting a child lets you update that info.

Now, the current app loads the data fine. The table names and data are loaded. The child data loads.
Everything is fine, but when it comes to loading the controls, we only use Textboxes.

On the usercontrol the code is:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AdditionalItemsTemplate">
            <Border>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label                             
                        Content="{Binding Name}"
                        Style="{StaticResource PanelLabelStyle}"/>
                    <TextBox                                                         
                        Text="{Binding Value}"                            
                        Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"/>

                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Border 
    Height="350"
    Width="{Binding Width}"
    Style="{StaticResource InnerMenuBorderStyle}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Width="230"                
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsUpdateEnabled}">
            <StackPanel>
                <Border
                    Margin="3,3,3,0"
                    Style="{StaticResource PanelBorderStyle}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource PanelLabelStyle}">
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding TableName}"
                                TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                        </Label>
                        <TextBox
                            Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                            Text="{Binding Value}"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        <ItemsControl 
                            Width="222"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding additionalFields}" Margin="0,0,-226,0"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AdditionalItemsTemplate}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <Button      
                    Width="70"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="3.5,0,0,0"
                    Template="{StaticResource UpdateButtonTemplate}"
                    Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="Update"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <Rectangle 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Grid.Column="1"              
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            Width="2" 
            StrokeDashArray="0.5 1.0 0.3" 
            Stroke="LightGray"
            Visibility="{Binding IsAddVisible}"/>
        <Border 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Width="230"                
            Visibility="{Binding IsAddVisible}">
            <StackPanel>
                <Border
                    Margin="3,3,3,0"
                    Style="{StaticResource PanelBorderStyle}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Content="{Binding LabelText}"
                            Style="{StaticResource PanelLabelStyle}"/>
                        <TextBox 
                            Grid.Row="1"                        
                            Text="{Binding NewLookup}"                        
                            Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"/>
                        <ItemsControl   
                            Width="222"
                            Margin="0,0,-226,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding childAdditionalFields}"                                 
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AdditionalItemsTemplate}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <Button 
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Width="50"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="3.5,0,0,0"
                    Template="{StaticResource AddButtonTemplate}"                
                    Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="Add"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

In the resources, the AdditionalItemsTemplate loads a label for each column name, and the textbox is loaded with the values, or can be used to enter new values

I would like to make just **ONE** datepicker for **ONE** table.
So for example. In table Students, the fields are Name (varchar), Age (varchar), DateStarted (date). A textbox loads for Name and Age, but just for DateStarted a datepicker should load.

So far, in the resources, i add `<local:DatePicker 
                                          SelectedDate="{Binding Value}"
                                          Visibility="{Binding DateVisible}"/>` 
So that when the table Student is loaded, the visibility of the datepicker is changed from being hidden to visible.

Here is a sample of the ViewModel:

```
public AddUpdateConfigurationViewModel(TreeViewContainer treeViewContainer, List<AddChangeSiteConfigurationViewModel> lookupTypeList, FieldDataResponse fieldDataResponse)
    {
        NewLookup = String.Empty;
        Width = 480;
        DateVisible = "Hidden";
        IsAddVisible = "Hidden";
        IsUpdateEnabled = false;
        if (treeViewContainer.AdditionalFields != null)
        {
            if (treeViewContainer.AdditionalFields.Count() > 0)
            {
                treeViewContainer.AdditionalFields.RemoveAll(x => x.Name.Contains("ID"));
                treeViewContainer.AdditionalFields.RemoveAll(x => x.Name.Contains("Guid"));
            }
        }      
        if (treeViewContainer.AdditionalFields != null)
            this.additionalFields = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewContainer>(treeViewContainer.AdditionalFields);
        if ((treeViewContainer.ParentTable == null) | (treeViewContainer.ParentTable == String.Empty))
            IsUpdateEnabled = true;
        var lookupTypes = lookupTypeList.Where(x => x.Parent_Field == "ID" + treeViewContainer.TableName);
        if (treeViewContainer.ParentTable == "IsParent")
        {
            IsAddVisible = "Visible";
            DateVisible = "Hidden";
            LabelText = "New " + treeViewContainer.Name;
            TableName = treeViewContainer.TableName;
            childAdditionalFields = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewContainer>();
            foreach (var additionalField in treeViewContainer.AdditionalFields)
                childAdditionalFields.Add(new TreeViewContainer(additionalField.Name));
            if (treeViewContainer.Name.Equals("Student"))
            {

                DateVisible = "Visible";

            }
        }
        else if (lookupTypes.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var lookupType in lookupTypes)
            {
                IsAddVisible = "Visible";
                LabelText = "New " + lookupType.Name;
                TableName = lookupType.TableName;
                childAdditionalFields = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewContainer>();
                foreach (var additionalChildField in lookupType.additionalFieldsDictionary)
                    childAdditionalFields.Add(new TreeViewContainer(additionalChildField.Key));
            }
        }
        else
            Width = 250;                  
        this.Name = treeViewContainer.Name;
        this.Value = treeViewContainer.Name;
        this.ID = treeViewContainer.ID;
        this.treeViewContainer = treeViewContainer;
        this.lookupTypeList = lookupTypeList;
        this.fieldDataResponse = fieldDataResponse;
    }
```

I hope this makes sense.

Now when i load the usercontrol and select on another table, sometimes the datepicker is visible, even though the visibility is set to Hidden.
And when the Student table is selected, there are datepickers under textboxes for every field.

How do I go about just making one datepicker for this one table?

If there is any more info needed, I will edit and update accordingly

EDIT

Screenshots
This is how the treeview loads. all the tables in the db are listed here
[image]
now clicking on a table that shouldn't have the datepicker does this:
[image]
it adds the datepicker to this treeview container. i want to eliminate this,
and this is where it should be
[image]
but i have too many, see. there should only be one added here. not all the way down, under every textbox.

and the Visible setting is just a temp fix, until i get this datepicker sorted. the visibility can be tackled later

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a screenshot? I can't really visualize how it works. Btw. having DateVisible as a string rather than a Visibility enum type (or convert from bool -> Visibility) could be prone to errors from spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think adding a datepicker and trying to show/hide it is the best way to go. A better way is to load a datatemplate which matches the type which is being bound to. So if the column is a datetime type, you should load a datatemplate which has a label and a datepicker. This is what the [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) is for. You create a class which extends DataTemplateSelector, and decide which template to return, based on the object being bound to.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DateTimeFieldTemplate">
        <Border>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label                             
                    Content="{Binding Name}"
                    Style="{StaticResource PanelLabelStyle}"/>
                <local:DatePicker                                                         
                    SelectedDate="{Binding Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TextFieldTemplate">
        <Border>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label                             
                    Content="{Binding Name}"
                    Style="{StaticResource PanelLabelStyle}"/>
                <TextBox                                                         
                    Text="{Binding Value}"                            
                    Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"/> 
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:TemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector" DateTimeFieldTemplate="{StaticResource DateTimeFieldTemplate}" TextFieldTemplate="{StaticResource TextFieldTemplate}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}"/>
</Grid>
```

You illustrate in your original code that you have a Name and Value property, so you only need to decide on how to provide information on what datatype the Value property is. One way is to make an interface with a Value property of type object:

```
public interface IBoundDataColumn
{
    public string Name { get; } // Not really necessary for the template selector, but perhaps for completeness
    public object Value { get; }
}

public class DateTimeColumn : IBoundDataColumn
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate TextFieldTemplate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DataTemplate DateTimeFieldTemplate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {
        IBoundDataColumn boundCol = item as IBoundDataColumn;

        if (boundCol.Value.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            return DateTimeFieldTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
            return TextFieldTemplate;
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

Or you could have a DataType property:

```
public interface IBoundDataColumn
{
    public Type DataType {get;}
}

public class DateTimeColumn : IBoundDataColumn
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime Value {get;set;}
    public Type DataType { get { return typeof(DateTime); } }
}
```

Or you could avoid the interface altogether and use reflection to get the type dynamically:

```
public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
{
    var p = item.GetType().GetProperty("Value");

    if (t.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
    ...
}
```

Comment: trying to implement this DataTemplateSelector. btw, what is the reflection solution? is there a link for me to search up on?

Comment: I have updated the answer to illustrate the reflection solution

Comment: thanks. gonna work on it and report back in a day or two